# UiLabel text goes out from ViewController Swift

Tags: uilabel, swift4

As i'm newbie and stuck in this problem from many days. As i'm working with Read More/Less UILabel. As **Read More/Less Button** working fine but the problem is when i click Read More Button, then Label content goes out from ViewController. I have also tried with scrollView but facing same problem that Content goes out.  I don't know the length of content because i'm getting from server. Is this possible, When click on Read More Button, then  the Label get space on ViewController on the base of content accordingly.

Also after clicking Read More/Less, rest of the controls that are below to REad More/Less remains same.

currently i'm using this code for Read More/Less

```
import UIKit

class ExpandedLabelViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

var isLabelAtMaxHeight = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myLabel.text = ""bla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla bla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla Ahtazaz""

    myLabel.numberOfLines = 2

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if myLabel.numberOfLines == 0 {
        myLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    } else {
        myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    }
}

}
```

Any hep will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add ScrollView

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

And then you need to handle scroll view content size on button tap like that:

```
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    {
        if myLabel.numberOfLines == 0 {
            myLabel.numberOfLines = 2
            myLabel.sizeToFit()
            /// height = myLabel.frame.size.height + MyLabel y origin(30)
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: myLabel.frame.size.height + 30)
        } else {
            myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            myLabel.sizeToFit()
            print(myLabel.frame)
            /// height = myLabel.frame.size.height + MyLabel y origin(30)
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: myLabel.frame.size.height + 30)
        }
    }
```

I have added a demo for you. You can check in this demo:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/eeqf465ecbi8lay/LabelDemo-2.zip?dl=0

Comment: Great, working perfectly but a little problem, When i placed controls  above or below to Label, then Labels or other controls are not proper working(I have also asked this in Question), Mean that when Label expand or when not expand, rest of the controls position remain same, like remain below or above properly when expanding or when not expanding. Let me know if you didn't understand yet, what i'm asking. Hope so, we are just near to our solution. Thanks

Comment: My answer is according to your question. If you have other question then ask?

Comment: You need to Use Stack view for that to maintain other controll position according to label.

Comment: Great help again :) Thanks

Comment: Please help me if you can, if it's possible please create a demo in which  use That above type of label and use some other controls above and below on it.

Comment: Great bro. If you need any help. I will be there for you

Comment: Bro, i didn't solved my problem properly. Here is a demo https://www.dropbox.com/sh/linff5bisz234v0/AADTxuZ_zQonAbp0q28E9QLda?dl=0  that i did. When i want to expand label using Button click, it works fine, but when again click on Button, Button not worked. Also tell me, Is this approach is good using multiple controllers? If not, please make a same demo using stackView, Please. Thanks

Comment: Waiting for your kind response.

Comment: Hi, need help in above comment, please

Comment: Hi.. I am out of town.. sorry for late reply

Comment: ok, But plz asap. i'm stuck in this problem. I have tried multiple ways but didn't got good results.

Comment: Also your demo is excellent, worked greatly when Tap. But i don't know, why this is not working with using clicking button.

Comment: Hi, Look at this Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009489/add-fabfloatingactionbutton-on-uibutton-in-tableviewcell-swift